# How to insert customBatch in Google Content API (Shopping)

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-shopping-api

I am trying to insert products on Google Merchant Center. I am currently using Google API PHP client, and I am unable to find toSimpleObject function in any of the class and class extending it.

```
$this->service = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent($client);

$product = array("batchId" => $batchID,
                      "merchantId" => $this->googleapi->merchantID,
                      "method" => "insert",
                      "product" => array(
                        "kind" => "content#product",
                        "offerId" => $skuDetails['SKU'],
                        "title" => $skuDetails['TITLE'],
                        "description" => $skuDetails['DESCRIPTION'],
                        "imageLink" => $skuDetails['IMAGE'],
                        "contentLanguage" => "en",
                        "targetCountry" => "US",
                        "channel" => "online",
                        "availability" => ($skuDetails['QUANTITY'] > 0)?'in stock':'out of stock',
                        "brand" => $skuDetails['BRAND'],
                        "condition" => $skuDetails['CONDITION'],
                        "minHandlingTime" => $skuDetails['HANDLING_TIME'],
                        "ageGroup" => 'adult',
                        "maxHandlingTime" => ($skuDetails['HANDLING_TIME'] + 2),
                        "googleProductCategory" => (empty($skuDetails['CATEGORYID']))?$skuDetails['CATEGORYPATH']:$skuDetails['CATEGORYID'],
                        "price" => [
                          "value" => $price['lp'],
                          "currency" => "USD"
                        ]
                      )
                    );


$productObject = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_ProductsCustomBatchRequest();
$productObject->setEntries($product);

$result = $this->service->products->custombatch($productObject);
```

Error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Google_Service_ShoppingContent_ProductsCustomBatchRequest::toSimpleObject()

Line Number: 108

Backtrace:

File: vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/ShoppingContent/Resource/Products.php
Line: 40
Function: call
```

Comment: In my case, this issue was because I had been using the same class name as same as it was in Google API (Vendor) and Project file (Where I was using this invoking the API). The class name due to which error was generate is "Google_model". I have modified that and know its working fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Product` to insert data to your product instance then you can use custombatch to upload it

```
 $product = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Product();

 $product->setId($id);
 $product->setTitle($title);
```

Comment: This won't work if you need to insert products in batch. My question is related to batch upload